# Getting all participants with group by and self join

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have below table. Here is the whole schema.[chat_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zHRM.png)

```
Paricipant
--------------------------------------
id | user_id | group_id | is_blocked
----------------------------------------
1 |   20     |   12     | false
2 |   21     |   12     | false
3 |   20     |   13     | false
4 |   22     |   13     | false
5 |   20     |   14     | false
6 |   23     |   14     | false
7 |   24     |   14     | false

User
--------------------------------------
id | username 
----------------------------------------
20 |   Mike     
21 |   Selly     
22 |   Ruby
23 |   Catherine
24 |   Monica
```

So I need to find all the groups a user belongs, and that group should include other user's who belongs to same group.

so for user 20, there are groups 12, 13 and 14. I need also the list of users who belongs to the same group.

```
where user_id
 group_id (maybe using group_by) 
 list of users with username who belongs to same group except one with user_id
```

This is what I have tired so far.

```
SELECT "ChatParticipant"."id", "ChatParticipant"."group_id", "Self"."id" AS "Self.id", "Self"."user_id" AS "Self.user_id", "Self"."group_id" AS "Self.group_id", "Self"."is_blocked" AS "Self.is_blocked", "Self"."createdAt" AS "Self.createdAt", "Self"."updatedAt" AS "Self.updatedAt", "Self->User"."id" AS "Self.User.id", "Self->User"."username" AS "Self.User.username"
FROM "ChatParticipants" AS "ChatParticipant"
LEFT OUTER
JOIN "ChatParticipants" AS "Self" ON "ChatParticipant"."group_id" = "Self"."group_id"
LEFT OUTER
JOIN "Users" AS "Self->User" ON "Self"."user_id" = "Self->User"."id"
WHERE "ChatParticipant"."user_id" = 14;
```

This is what I want. Here `user_id` will be passed in where clause.

```
-----------------------
user_id | group_id | usernames
20      | 12       | Selly
20      | 14       | Catherine, Monica
20      | 13       | Ruby
```

How can I achieve this. Please help If I can do self join and how. Thanks.

Comment: Please add your desired result.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
select user_id,group_id,group_concat(username order by t1id) linkedusers
from
(
select t.user_id,t.group_id,t1.user_id t1id,t1.group_id t1group_id, u.username
from t
join t t1 on t1.group_id = t.group_id
join u on u.id = t1.user_id 
where t.user_id = 20
) s
where t1id <> 20
group by user_id,group_id
;
```

Comment: But that schema is perfectly normalize. Why the queries are so complex? I just need the goup names in which user is involved in but, it should also give all the user's username in that group

Comment: ..But it does give the result you asked for.